# how to make the data of the "data" function reverberate in the graph?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

i have a graph that i want to use two files with the points of it. I would like to know how I can change between the two files with a selector. I made the following code but the graph doesn't change after selecting. I believe the "date" data is overwritten but not reflected in the chart. What can I do?

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <select @change="onChange($event)">
      <option value="dataFile1">file one</option>
      <option value="dataFile2">file two</option>
    </select>
    <LineGraph2 :vul_data="data"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import LineGraph2 from '@/components/LineGraph2.vue';

import {data1} from '@/data/file1.js'
import {data2} from '@/data/file2.js'

@Component({
  components: {
    LineGraph2,
  },
})
export default class HomeView extends Vue {
  data() {
    return {
      data: data1,
    }
  }
  
  onChange(event: any) {
    if(event.target != null){
      this.data = data2 as any
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use chart.js you need to call the update function on your chart after you change the data but i don't see how you pass the new data to the component (i didn't use Vue before so i am just asking to check if you passed new data correctly)